# ubuntu - Cannot connect to mongodb remotely

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, networking, flutter, ubuntu-16.04

I have a mongodb server running in my Ubuntu laptop (16.04 LTS). I am able to do all CRUD operations from a mobile app (developed in flutter) which is connected to same wireless network as my Ubuntu machine.

But I am unable to do any database transactions when I try to interact with the database from a mobile on mobile network or remotely from outside even though I made below changes in Ubuntu machine. The frustrating part is that I am not getting any error message when I put the debug points in my flutter application.

1) Changed the IP from dynamic to static.
2) Commented bind_IP in etc/mongod.conf.
3) Opened firewalls for ports 80, 443, 27017 using sudo ufw allow commands.

Please advise.

Comment: did you open firewall and make port-forwarding on Router (which connect to internet ) for port 27017 ?

Comment: I tried port-forwarding on my Verizon router for port 27017 and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect to mongodb remotely now. Solution is Dynamic DNS which points a hostname to your dynamic IP address

1) I registered in a free dynamic DNS providing website and got myself a free domain name which points to my router IP.

2) In router settings, I did port forwarding from external IP to the static IP of the device on the port 27017. (As mentioned earlier, I converted the IP to a static IP in my machine which has MongoDB)